# json file nested column value is coming as null in pyspark

Tags: json, pyspark

json file:
`"products":[{"productId":"8d809e13-fdc5-4d15-9271-  953750f6d592","quantity":500,"soldPrice":104.852}, {"productId":"ec15ba1d-53b6-44b0-8a22-  1e498485f1b8","quantity":300,"soldPrice":94.3668}, {"productId":"e672483e-57a8-434a-bc42-  ecf827c8a8d4","quantity":1000,"soldPrice":109.57034}], "shippingAddress":{"attention":"Khaleesi Frost","address":"493 Augustine Drive N ","city":"Miramar","state":"FL","zip":"33785"}`

I can access the 'products' using explode method as it's ArrayType. But the 'shippingAddress' values are coming as null.

```
`select(F.col("shippingAddress.attention").alias("shipping_address_attention"),
   F.col("shippingAddress.address").alias("shipping_address_address"))`
```

json Schema:
`StructField('shippingAddress' , StructType([ StructField('attention' , StringType(), True), StructField('address' , StringType(), True),                                 StructField('city' , StringType(), True), StructField('state' , StringType(), True), StructField('zip' , IntegerType(), True) ]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have a valid JSON [here](https://jsonlint.com/).

If you are using same JSON as you posted in your question then you should enclose whole JSON within {}. While reading JSON use option `multiline` as True.

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> df = spark.read.option('multiline', True).json('file.json')
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- products: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- productId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- quantity: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- soldPrice: double (nullable = true)
 |-- shippingAddress: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- address: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- attention: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- zip: string (nullable = true)

>>> df.select(col("shippingAddress.attention").alias("shipping_address_attention"),col("shippingAddress.address").alias("shipping_address_address")).show(truncate=False)
+--------------------------+------------------------+
|shipping_address_attention|shipping_address_address|
+--------------------------+------------------------+
|Khaleesi Frost            |493 Augustine Drive N   |
+--------------------------+------------------------+
```

**UPDATE**

You have mentioned zip column type as IntegerType() but in JSON it's string, due to this type mismatch you are getting Null in the column. so change type to StringType() in your custom schema.

Your schema should be,

```
StructType([StructField('shippingAddress' , StructType([ StructField('attention' , StringType(), True), StructField('address' , StringType(), True),                                 
StructField('city' , StringType(), True), StructField('state' , StringType(), True), StructField('zip' , StringType(), True) ]))])
```

Comment: The json file is valid. I'm reading the json files as stream and loading into table.
read:
`orders = (
  spark
    .readStream
    .format("json")
    .schema(jason_schema)           
    .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
    .option("path",f"{stream_path}")
    .load()
)`

write:
`df6 = df5.writeStream.format("delta").outputMode("append")
.partitionBy("submitted_yyyy_mm").queryName("orders").trigger(processingTime='20 seconds') .option("checkpointLocation", f"{orders_checkpoint_path}").table("${orders_table}")`
In table those shipping values are coming as null.

Comment: Updated the answer please check.

Comment: Yes, after changing that to StringType, it has worked now. Thank you so much :-)

Comment: @Uttam_Singh Consider to mark this answer as accepted, it helps us to keep answering the community

Comment: @Kafels Thanks. wasn't aware of this. I have accepted it now.